# Is it possible to dynamically update basename in history?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history, html5-history

Is it possible to update basename dynamically from the history package?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/history

To me it looks like you set this only once and then it's reused internally by the module to automatically add the basename to the url if the user navigates to a url where the basename is not present:

```
createBrowserHistory({
    basename: getLocale(), //en, sv, ...
})
```

And i can't use the following, because that won't automatically change the url from `'/'` to `'/en'`:

```
<Router history={history} basename={`/${props.locale}`}>
    ...
</Router>
```

Use case:

- I want to change the basename without refreshing the page
- I want the basename to contain the language locale ex: `en`
- I want the basename to be automatically added to the url if the user goes to a url which does not contain the basename

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. I have an `id` in the base URL of where my app lives and when I do a push I just end up with a url that includes `/:id/` instead of the replacement value. I tried including `id` in the second `state` parameter of the `push` method, but that didn't work either. I'm pretty sure I stumbled upon something that eluded to it not being possible. I am surprised your particular case didn't work though. I was able to set the basename with a variable essentially the way you are with `createBrowserHistory`.